# Zend Framework not finding forms in modular application

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a Zend Framework modular application set up. One of my modules is called 'frontend' and it is the default module (`resources.frontController.defaultModule = "frontend"` is in my config file).

I have a form, `Frontend_Form_PropertySearch` located at **/application/modules/frontend/forms/PropertySearch.php** and attempting to use it in my controller as follows:

```
public function searchAction()
{
    $form = new Frontend_Form_PropertySearch();

    $form->submit->setLabel('Search');
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Frontend_Form_PropertySearch' not found in /Users/Martin/Dropbox/Repositories/realestatecms/application/modules/frontend/controllers/PropertiesController.php on line 17

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is your appnamespace Frontend or is it something else?  See [Application Autoloading](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.core-functionality.html#zend.application.core-functionality.bootstrap-bootstrap)

Comment: `appnamespace` is still set to 'Application' in my config file.

Comment: In that case BartekR's first method should work.  You could shorten it by removing the `resourceTypes` array if you are using the default Zend Application autoloader mappings.  You can also just add it to your application bootstrap as in ZF1 all bootstraps are run regardless of your current module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of solutions could be adding file `application/modules/frontend/Bootstrap.php` and put this (similar working on one of my projects):

```
<?php
class Frontend_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'Frontend_',
            'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH .'/modules/frontend',
            'resourceTypes' => array (
                'form' => array(
                    'path' => 'forms',
                    'namespace' => 'Form',
                ),
                'model' => array(
                    'path' => 'models',
                    'namespace' => 'Model',
                ),
            )
        ));
        return $autoloader;
    }
}
```

Another solution, as described by akrabat: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/bootstrapping-modules-in-zf-1-8/

```
// file application.ini
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""

File: /application/modules/frontend/Bootstrap.php

<?php
class Frontend_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

}
```

Second one uses default resource autoloader as described in documentation: http://framework.zend.com/manual/zh/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html#zend.loader.autoloader-resource.module

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ini file contains these lines

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/path/to/your/modules"
resources.modules[] =
```